# How can delegate method run before ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, delegates, viewcontroller

- 1.`ViewControllerA` sent `ViewControllerB` a key with delegate
- 2.When `ViewControllerB` been loaded the key value is correct, but I need to use the key for `viewDidLoad`

So the problem is:How can delegate method run first so i can use the key in `viewDidLoad`?OR:is there a way to use this key while `viewDidLoad` if can't make delegate run before `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: how are you sending the Delegate key..?

Comment: Inorder to pass the key, you are calling any method in VCA or just set any property in VCB from VCA???

Comment: set property in VCB from VCA and need to use it in VCB's ViewDidLoad method @Anil

Comment: If you are setting property from VCA it will be there before calling viewDidLoad in VCB. try to log the value in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do something like this:

lets say that your key is a String,

1) in your **ViewControllerB.h** add

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *keyFromParent;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil WithKey:(NSString *)key bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

2) in your **ViewControllerB.m** replace your **initWithNibName** method with

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil WithKey:(NSString *)key bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.keyFromParent = key;
    }
    return self;
}
```

3) When you present the **ViewControllerB** from the **ViewControllerA** do it like this,

```
ViewControllerB *controller = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" WithKey:KEY_FROM_DELEGATE bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

4) Now you can use the **keyFromParent** which is the value passed from the **ViewControllerA** in the **viewDidLoad** method of the **ViewControllerB**

Hope this answer would help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Write an initialiser method in `ViewControllerB` something like `initWithNibName:bundle:key:delegate:` Something like shown below

```
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
            bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
               key:(NSString*)aKey
          delegate:(id) aDelegate
{
    self=[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self) {
        // Save aDelegate and aKey as properties
    }
    return self;
}
```

After init the viewDidLoad will get called where you can use these property values.

Cheers!
Amar.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a variable value to ViewControllerB from ViewControllerA, then create property of that Variable in ViewControllerB with readWrite authority and assign it in ViewControllerA just before navigating to ViewControllerB.

if it is string variable to pass 
write in viewControllerB.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *variableName;
```

and in ViewControllerA when you are navigating to viewControllerB

```
viewControllerB *obj = [[viewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewControllerB" bundle:nil];

obj.variableName = @"Your Value";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
```